# Add to list then sort vs FindLastIndex then insert

Tags: c#, list

I have a List of items sorted a property. i want to add another item to the list and still get a sorted list. i see 2 simple ways to do this but which is faster/ better?

- Add item to list then Sort the list OR
- Use FindLastIndex then Insert item on index + 1

Or is there another way that i do not know of?

Comment: Have you tried to benchmark both of them? The answer is pretty obvious.

Comment: regarding another way: if the items are (or have to be) unique, you can use a `SortedSet<>` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Or, since you mention it's sorted by a property, a `SortedList<>` where the property is used as the key

Comment: If you go with the first one than you might need to know what algorithm you are using, most probably QuickSort if you are using microsoft implementation. complexity O(n log n) in average case[fine]. if you go with second way again you need to write algorithm and that is totally depend on your algorithm in worst or average case.  suppose you are adding the number which is highest in the list?

Answer (score 2):

Here is some interesting facts:

> Option 1: 1) Inserting all items in list. Just inserting will take
>   O(1). 2) Sort the list by some sorting algorithm. Fastest worst case
>   is O(n log n).
>
> Option 2: 1) Find. Using Binary search, worst case is O(log n), but not your case :)  (Your
>   case using FindLastIndex which is a predicate: This [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzs5503w(v=vs.110).aspx) is an
>   O(n) operation, where n is the Length of array.) 2) Insert the number
>   would be O(1).

Basically if you want to add items just in the last index second option definitely is faster and the best option.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion I think

> > Use FindLastIndex then Insert item on index + 1

should be better because in resorting at least process will walk over the list once :)

Comment: should be better because in resorting at least the process will walk over the list once :)

Comment: so you are comparing each and every element with the input. suppose your element is the highest one and the list is of 1 million records.

Comment: use binary search :)

Comment: in a 1 million records resorting at least it will read the wall items in the list once